# AHK pixelgetcolor and pixelsearch simply don't work

Tags: autohotkey

I have the following two functions that aren't working

```
CheckConditionColor()
{
cond = -1

while cond = -1
{

    pixelgetcolor, cond, 137, 298, RGB
    if cond = F1F1F1 ;excellent
        return 3
        
    pixelgetcolor, cond, 77, 302, RGB
    if cond = AAAAAA ;normal
        return 0
    pixelgetcolor, cond, 78, 301, RGB
    if cond = F1F1F1 ;poor
        return 1
    pixelgetcolor, cond, 105, 297, RGB
    if cond = 123123 ;good
        return 2
}

}
```

as well as

```
CheckConditionColor()
{
;pixelgetcolor, condition, 65, 300, RGB
errorlevel = -1

while errorlevel = -1
{
    pixelsearch,,, 64, 300, 68, 306, C2FFFF, 10, fast rgb ;needs to come first prolly
        if errorlevel >= 0
            return 3 ;excellent
    pixelsearch,,, 64, 300, 68, 306, FFFFFF, 10, fast rgb
        if errorlevel >= 0
            return 0 ;normal 
    pixelsearch,,, 64, 300, 68, 306, 656565, 10, fast rgb
        if errorlevel >= 0
            return 1 ;poor
    pixelsearch,,, 64, 300, 68, 306, FFA0D9, 10, fast rgb
        if errorlevel >= 0
            return 2 ;good
    

;msgbox % errorlevel
}   

    
return -1

}
```

I know for a fact the colors are correct and that the pixel locations are correct. Through testing I know for a fact that it is possible to get colors from this program through this method. I put the while loops in just trying to force the issue, they're probably not necessary.

There's a function in the script that utilizes this, with two if statements.
`If cond <= 1`
and the other is
`if cond >= 2`

i have to assume there's something obvious i'm missing.

i broke it down to this:

```
]::
pixelgetcolor, cond, 77, 302, Slow RGB
if cond = AAAAAA
    ;return 0
    msgbox % cond
return
```

and get the expected result every time, so any ideas what i could be doing wrong? I'd prefer to focus on getting the first method i listed working, as it seems more reliable for this application.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
pixelgetcolor, cond, 77, 302, Slow RGB
if cond = 0xF0F0F0
```

0x prefix is needed when you are using hexa-decimal values

https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/SetFormat.htm